# Resources for learning Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to learn Emacs, and was wondering if anyone had any good resources (free or otherwise) to recommend. I'm mostly interested in programming Emacs, starting from the basics, and lots of "exercises". I have used Emacs and most of its editing features, although I'm a bit rusty so a very quick refresher on that would be useful as well.

Thanks

Edit: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll have a look and update with what I liked...

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210791/good-resources-for-emacs and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311221/what-to-teach-a-beginner-in-emacs

Comment: [PeepCode](http://peepcode.com/products/meet-emacs) has a great introduction to EMACS.

Answer (score 7):

1. [GNU Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/emacs.html)
2. [GNU Emacs lisp reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html)
3. [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/)

Comment: The Emacs Lisp reference is a good start.

Answer (score 5):

[Programming in Emacs Lisp (Second Edition)](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/emacs-lisp-intro.html) - free online book

Answer (score 5):

One thing to bear in mind is that all emacs configuration is programming.

[PlanetEmacsen](https://web.archive.org/web/20190203120729/http://planet.emacsen.org/atom.xml) is a good RSS feed with lots of tips.

[Xah Lee](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs.html) although he is apparently considered a bad troll, has some great emacs programming stuff.

Also whenever there's a function or keyboard shortcut you're not sure of, try C-h f  and C-h k  respectively, then follow the link to the source code for that command.

For exercises, [Lair of the DustBunny](https://dustbunnylair.blogspot.com/2008/07/creating-python-mode-for-emacs-from.html) did a very long series on rewriting python mode from scratch.

You could also try writing the [PLEAC](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/) elisp section.  That's a very good way to compare elisp to your favourite language.

Comment: "One thing to bear in mind is that all emacs configuration is programming."  While strictly speaking that's true (it's all elisp under the hood), customize (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) makes simple things simple.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs itself includes a tutorial with exercises that guides you through the basic features and editing commands. You can find it in the Menu under 'Help' or by pressing C-h t (i.e. press Control and 'h' together and then 't' alone).

Comment: Yeah, I know the tutorial. Unfortunately, it's only about editing and working with files, without any elisp.

Answer (score 1):

Last week I purchased this Peepcode screencast and really liked it. It walks you through the basic features (editing, loading saving, buffers) but also dives into some advances topics, like programming emacs lisp:

http://peepcode.com/products/meet-emacs

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the best book about Emacs is [Bob Glickstein's "Writing GNU Emacs Extensions".](http://www.emacs.uniyar.ac.ru/doc/O%27Reilly_Emacs/Writing%20GNU%20Emacs%20Extensions.PDF)

Really informative. Really good examples. And, for a technical book a pleasure to read. It is one of the best computer books I have. (Thereunder are such treasures like my "VIC-20 Technical Manual" from 1982 :-)

Some PDFs are available online, but for the full fun I suggest purchasing a hard-copy.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs's own help system is your friend --- ***ask Emacs***. Learn the main <kbd>C-h</kbd> keys and `apropos`.

These too can help:

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HelpPlus
- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNewbieWithIcicles